ElasticSearch Error: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Not a valid protocol version

We recently upgraded our development environment from Elasticsearch cluster version 8.6.2 to 8.15.1

We are using the High Level Rest Client with **apiCompatibilityMode=true
**

After the upgrade, we started seeing sporadic 500 errors from Elastic queries. We had not seen these prior to the upgrade and we had apiCompatibilityMode set to true earlier as well.

When this happens we can see following exceptions in the logs:


org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Not a valid protocol version: 0* at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:209) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:245) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:121) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) at 
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) Caused by: org.apache.http.ParseException: Not a valid protocol version: 0 at 
    org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseProtocolVersion(BasicLineParser.java:134) at 
    org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseStatusLine(BasicLineParser.java:366) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpResponseParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:112) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpResponseParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:50) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeadLine(AbstractMessageParser.java:156) at 
    org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:207)


Digging through the TRACE level logs of the Elasticsearch client and Apache have yielded no results and it's still unclear why this issue is sporadically happening

We have been unable to replicate the issue through curl or kibana

We have tried a few configuration changes in the Http Client, but have not been able to stabilize our Dev environment so far

One additional point to share, which we found interesting is, when we set ConnectionReuseStrategy on the RestClientBuilder (using setHttpClientConfigCallback) to NoConnectionReuseStrategy, the protocolException does not appear anymore. However, we do not want to go with this solution as it would not reuse connections.


Please advise if anyone has ran into this problem and any suggestions to help resolve it.

We have tried a few configuration changes in the Http Client, but have not been able to stabilize our Dev environment so far

Digging through the TRACE level logs of the Elasticsearch client and Apache have yielded no results and it's still unclear why this issue is sporadically happening

One additional point to share, which we found interesting is, when we set ConnectionReuseStrategy on the RestClientBuilder (using setHttpClientConfigCallback) to NoConnectionReuseStrategy, the protocolException does not appear anymore. However, we do not want to go with this solution as it would not reuse connections.



Do you have a minimal example of your RestClient configuration and operation?

I think its possible that you are falling victim to the very interesting problem described here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/92032
The HEAD requests with chunked responses seem to have been the culprit, causing bad HTTP parsing. This should be fixed in version 8.6.2, but i wonder if the comment regarding apiCompatibilityMode is still in effect:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/92032#issuecomment-1333569002
If possible, you could attempt to diagnose with PCAPs to replicate the behaviour seen the linked github issue (the trailing bytes). The only fix i could imagine if this is indeed the case, is to remove apiCompatibilityMode :(

Thanks for your response and for sharing those insights on what could be causing this error. I did try remove apiCompatibilityMode but that didn't help either. At this stage, we are thinking of switching to Java API Client unless there are any other suggestions. Thanks again!

Ah, thats unfortunate :( Good Luck!
